# Why does `docker-login` fail in BitBucket pipelines?

Tags: docker, bitbucket

**Aim**

to login to a private docker registry using BitBucket pipelines.

**Attempt**

Based on [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/running-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines-879254331.html) documentation the following bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
image: docker:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - docker login -u $D_REGISTRY_USER -p $D_REGISTRY_PASS $D_REGISTRY_URL

options:
  docker: true
```

was created. When BitBucket pipelines run this it results in:

```
+ docker login -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD 
$DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon 
(Error response from daemon: authorization denied by plugin pipelines: Command 
not supported.). 
Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Error response from daemon: authorization denied by plugin pipelines: Command 
not supported.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment the `docker login` and `docker push` commands are only available to Pipelines Alpha members.

You can read about the features available to Alpha at "[Pipelines Alpha](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/pipelines-alpha-877358733.html)".

In order to participate, the above link includes instructions on how you can opt-in to the added functionality.

Personally I received an e-mail from Atlassian a day after signing up saying my projects now include Alpha features. So this feature works in my pipelines without any issues.

Comment: `Pipelines Alpha` - `Your response has been recorded.` I will accept the answer, when the issue is solved, i.e. when docker runs in our repository.